# Best way to complete Through the Fire and Flames if you dont play guitar

Tags: rock-band-3

What is the best way to complete Through the Fire and Flames if you don't play guitar?

Comment: Practice, practice, practice!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can complete the song with any of the other available instruments. I find singing easiest. It's just figuring out what you're good at and using that. Unless you mean you don't have a guitar controller? In that case you're kind of out of luck as far as I know. You need an instrument and or microphone.